# httpObj.getResponseHeader("location") is null after requet post

Tags: jquery, https

I have the following ajax function:

```js
function sendData() {
  var jsonTextArea = JSON.parse($("#json").val());
  var formData = JSON.stringify(jsonTextArea);
  var urlEnvio = "https://100.10.10.100/page/home&info=" & jsonTextArea; // esta url es la App de Angular

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlEnvio,
    data: formData,
    beforeSend: function(request) {},
    complete: function(httpObj) {
      switch (1 * httpObj.status) {
        case 200:
          alert("OK");
          break;
        case 300:
          window.location.replace(httpObj.getResponseHeader("location"));
          break;
        case 301:
          alert("Redireccion 301");
          break;
        case 302:
          alert("Redireccion 302");
          break;
        case 405:
          alert("Método 405");
          break;
      }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log("Respuesta: " + error);
    },
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
}
```

Right after doing the request post I want to redirect to the url:

```
var urlEnvio = "https://100.10.10.100/page/home&info=" & jsonTextArea;
```

But when the case is 300, the next sentence, has a value of null:

```
httpObj.getResponseHeader("location")
```

What is the problem? thanks,

Comment: You want to redirect to a url that you already have in a variable, why dont you just use `urlEnvio` instead of `httpObj.getResponseHeader("location")` ?

Comment: It also seems rather pointless to make an AJAX request to an endpoint you're going to redirect to anyway...

Comment: Have you had a look at the response in the dev tools? Does the location header exist? No all 3xx have a location header as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311671/http-responses-with-code-3xx-and-empty-location-header#21321976).

Comment: I need to make a request post from a static html send an object and getit in an Angular website (I can not use nodejs). urlEnvio is a application to Angular