# why does an empty header location path/filename in php worky differently in mobile browsers?

Tags: php, header

i don't need an explanation of how header location works, what i noticed is when i
use this with an `empty path` and `no filename` given
if the calling file is `index.php` and i do

`header("Location: ");`

the redirection works on a pc and redirect me to the `index.php` | `/` directory root

when i do the same on a smartphone or tablet(test with android) browser it redirect to `index.php` | `/` directory root sometimes it works, but sometimes i got an empty page and i have to refresh once and than i see the content, there is nothing special in the code only `set and unset of cookies` with php

so i have to do

`header("Location: index.php");`

Is this a bug or shouldn't you use an empty path, this example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197811/13508 - "only Firefox and old Edge accept empty Location headers; the new Edge and Chrome don't. " Answer is from 2019 so things may change, plus Android / iOS / Windows / Linux... browsers are typically different codebases.

Comment: Empty Location header can cause unpredictable behaviours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an empty path. Different browser implementations will handle that differently. In fact, the location header value should contain an absolute URL including the domain, but most, if not all, browsers will handle relative location header values.

Don't rely on it working!

Comment: @BlockchainOffice I assume the same rule applies: it depends on the implementation. But why would you want an empty location anyway? There's not much to gain with "" vs "/".